# How to create boxes with text and images inside them

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview

I want to create an UI similar to the one shown in the image.

It will basically have to a scrollable layout with set of boxes overlaying in relative layout over a map fragment each containing text as well images.

These boxes will be created dynamically (extracting from Twitter) and keep appearing and when increased in length the layout will become scrollable

I am done with setting the layout and the map, where I am stuck is I have no idea which items can be added and styled in this way providing such functionality.

If it would have been a web page I would use `div` for boxes and then `TextView`s and `ImageView`s for texts and images respectively but what is the `div` in android UI?

What I have searched so far I thnk ListView is the closest possible but I am not sure yet, so my questions are:

- Is it possible through `ListView`?
- Are there any other ways through which this can be done?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible through ListView?

Yes, `ListView` is most likely what you want using a `CustomAdapter` and create a separate `layout` to inflate in the `Adapter`'s `getView()` method. You can create the `layout` however you want using `TextView`s, `ImageView`s, etc...

> Are there any other ways through which this can be done?

There always is but if you want something with a list then `ListView` would probably be most appropriate.

[ListView tutorial](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vogella.com%2Farticles%2FAndroidListView%2Farticle.html&ei=DQJgUq3FIc7YyAHd54H4Bw&usg=AFQjCNEdO2iyq14pqIYW67PhxKzd3cQpkw&sig2=yTMebsUsoxUCcivr-LBRiQ&bvm=bv.54176721,d.aWc)

[ListView Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)